# @keycloak/keycloak-admin-client NestJS strange problem with role assigning

Tags: nestjs, keycloak, keycloak-admin-client

My aim is next: I want to assign using @keycloak/keycloak-admin-client new role for the group in realm and in the some specific client like using UI:[image]

For example I have created new role:

```
async createRole(createRoleInput: CreateRoleInput) {
    const client = await this.keycloakAdminService.getClient();
    await client.roles.create({
      ...createRoleInput,
      realm: 'space-realm',
    });

    return (await client.roles.find()).map(r => r.name);
  }
```

createRoleInput is an object, that includes just one field name, that will be used for role creation

Then I create a group using this code:

```
async createGroup(name: string) {
    const client = await this.keycloakAdminService.getClient();
    client.groups.create({
      realm: 'space-realm',
      name,
    });
  }
```

And the final task is to assign role to the realm and client using this group, that is happening in the following code:

```
async assignRoleToGroup(groupname: string, rolename: string) {
    const client = await this.keycloakAdminService.getClient();
    const groups = await client.groups.find({
      search: groupname
    });

    if (!groups.length) {
      throw new Error('No groups were found...')
    }

    const roles = await client.roles.find({
      search: rolename
    });

    if (!roles.length) {
      throw new Error('No roles were found...')
    }

    try {
      if (groups[0] && roles[0]) {
        const group = groups[0];
        const role = roles[0];

        await client.groups.addRealmRoleMappings({
          realm: 'space-realm',
          id: group.id,
          roles: [{
            id: role.id,
            name: role.name
          }]
        });

        const targetClients = await client.clients.find({
          clientId: 'finance-backend',
        })

        if (!targetClients.length) {
          throw new Error("Client wasn't identified");
        }

        const targetClient = targetClients[0];

        await client.groups.addClientRoleMappings({
          clientUniqueId: targetClient.id,
          id: group.id,
          roles: [{
            id: role.id,
            name: role.name
          }]
        })
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
    }

    return (await client.groups.find()).map(r => r.name);
  }
```

But maybe I did something wrong because I have got multiple times this error:

```
Error: { error: 'Role not found' }
```

in this part of the code :

```
await client.groups.addClientRoleMappings({
              clientUniqueId: targetClient.id,
              id: group.id,
              roles: [{
                id: role.id,
                name: role.name
              }]
            })
```

that is absolutely strange, because it has added this role to the realm without any similar troubles, using the same role. I will be very appreciated for the answer

Comment: The error is a `404 error`, it means that you are passing a role that doesn't exists. Could you check if the value of `role` is what you expect it to be?